# Snackbar replaces toast and unit tests crash when snackbar comes to foreground

Tags: android, android-snackbar, snackbar

I have replaced Toast with Snackbar in my code. I have added the following dependency in the corresponding build: `implementation('com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0-alpha01')`

```
private fun showMessageInSnackbar (message: String) {
        val snackbar = view?.let {
            Snackbar.make(it,
                message,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        }
  }
```

I can see the Snackbar working properly both in emulator and physical device. However when I run the unit tests of the fragment which have snackbar as outcome, test fails with message:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51 in com.xxxxxx.xxx:layout/design_layout_snackbar_include: Binary XML file line #51 in com.xxxxxx.xxx:layout/design_layout_snackbar_include: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51 in com.xxxxxx.xxx:layout/design_layout_snackbar_include: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

- **Note 1**: The junit do not test the snackbar or the text displayed.
- **Note 2**: What I see in *material-1.6.1-sources.jar/com/google/android/material/snackbar* is that symbol R is red/cannot be resolved

  import com.google.android.material.R;

The **design_layout_snackbar_include** mentioned above is
R.layout.design_layout_snackbar_include and R is not resolved.

Can anyone help on this issue? I believe that if I manage to resolve the R, I will be able to run my tests as well. But in general I have searched and tried many solutions without result!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue here. Any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing ui testing, and the snackbar shows above fragment, then the default activity to contain fragment is the `androidx.fragment.app.testing.EmptyFragmentActivity`

so you just need to add your activity before run into your test case

`val firstActivity: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java) firstActivity.launchActivity(Intent())`